# PostgreSQL 16, pgadmin crashing on MacOS

Tags: pgadmin, postgresql-16

I just spent about an hour creating a database for a project and upon closing pgadmin, it will now no longer open and crashes instantly. I tried rerunning the installer to upgrade my version and now am receiving this issue.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 0747B3D3-6300-4743-824F-795AEA478EDB
CrashReporter Key:   CF07D2E3-C626-FFA4-8820-BAC51AAC389C
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir10,1
Process:             pgAdmin 4 [3170]
Path:                /Applications/PostgreSQL 16/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/MacOS/pgAdmin 4
Identifier:          org.pgadmin.pgadmin4
Version:             7.6 (4280.88)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Default
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.pgadmin.pgadmin4 [1760]

Date/Time:           2023-10-23 23:09:41.6310 -0400
Launch Time:         2023-10-23 23:09:41.6131 -0400
OS Version:          macOS 12.6 (21G115)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00007ff7ffde09b0
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [3170]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   runtime                             0x7ff7ffde09b0 0x7ff7ffdc3000 + 121264
1   runtime                             0x7ff7ffde09f8 0x7ff7ffdc3000 + 121336
2   runtime                             0x7ff7ffdd71a4 0x7ff7ffdc3000 + 82340
3   runtime                             0x7ff7ffdd8288 0x7ff7ffdc3000 + 86664
4   runtime                             0x7ff7ffdd79fc 0x7ff7ffdc3000 + 84476
5   runtime                             0x7ff7ffdc6ae0 0x7ff7ffdc3000 + 15072
6   ???                                            0x3 ???


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000003   x2: 0x000000000000003c   x3: 0x000000000000002c
    x4: 0x0000000000000303   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x00000000000429c0
    x8: 0x00007ff7ffdfe000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x00007ff7ffdfe959
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x000001b900000100  x15: 0x00007ff7ffde6818
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffe1  x17: 0x00007ff7ffdef6e1  x18: 0x000000030e28302b  x19: 0x00007ff7ffdf42e1
   x20: 0x000000030e2836e0  x21: 0x0000000104ff3000  x22: 0x0000000000000004  x23: 0x0000000104ff3000
   x24: 0x0000000000000003  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x000000030e282b40  x27: 0x00000002052971b8
   x28: 0x000000030e28b910   fp: 0x000000030e281940   lr: 0x00007ff7ffde09a8
    sp: 0x000000030e281920   pc: 0x00007ff7ffde09b0 cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0x000000030e281958  esr: 0xf2000001 (Breakpoint) brk 1

Binary Images:
    0x7ff7ffdc3000 -     0x7ff7ffdf2fff runtime (*) <1f0f0114-cfb6-304b-8183-8ef52c21f8b4> /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

EOF

-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"pgAdmin 4","timestamp":"2023-10-23 23:09:41.00 -0400","app_version":"7.6","slice_uuid":"4c4c44e8-5555-3144-a1b6-fba2ce41498d","build_version":"4280.88","platform":0,"bundleID":"org.pgadmin.pgadmin4","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.6 (21G115)","incident_id":"0747B3D3-6300-4743-824F-795AEA478EDB","name":"pgAdmin 4"}
{
  "uptime" : 2100,
  "procLaunch" : "2023-10-23 23:09:41.6131 -0400",
  "procRole" : "Default",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookAir10,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 50517907344,
  "coalitionID" : 1760,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.6",
    "build" : "21G115",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-10-23 23:09:41.6310 -0400",
  "incident" : "0747B3D3-6300-4743-824F-795AEA478EDB",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 3170,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 50518322376,
  "translated" : true,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "procName" : "pgAdmin 4",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/PostgreSQL 16\/pgAdmin 4.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/pgAdmin 4",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"7.6","CFBundleVersion":"4280.88","CFBundleIdentifier":"org.pgadmin.pgadmin4"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"B12BE409-F14E-58F9-BD71-123892BA81BC","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "org.pgadmin.pgadmin4",
  "crashReporterKey" : "CF07D2E3-C626-FFA4-8820-BAC51AAC389C",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x00007ff7ffde09b0","rawCodes":[1,140703126391216],"type":"EXC_BREAKPOINT","signal":"SIGTRAP"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":5,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Trace\/BPT trap: 5","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":3170},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":38380,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":3},{"value":60},{"value":44},{"value":771},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":272832},{"value":140703126511616},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":140703126514009,"symbolLocation":241,"symbol":"__crashreporter_info__"},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1894080577792},{"value":140703126415384},{"value":18446744073709551585},{"value":140703126451937},{"value":13122416683},{"value":140703126471393},{"value":13122418400},{"value":4378800128},{"value":4},{"value":4378800128},{"value":3},{"value":1},{"value":13122415424},{"value":8676536760,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"dyld_all_image_infos"},{"value":13122451728}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":140703126391208},"cpsr":{"value":1610616832},"fp":{"value":13122410816},"sp":{"value":13122410784},"esr":{"value":4060086273,"description":"(Breakpoint) brk 1"},"pc":{"value":140703126391216,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":13122410840}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":121264,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":121336,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":82340,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":86664,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":84476,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":15072,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":3,"imageIndex":1}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 140703126269952,
    "size" : 196608,
    "uuid" : "1f0f0114-cfb6-304b-8183-8ef52c21f8b4",
    "path" : "\/usr\/libexec\/rosetta\/runtime",
    "name" : "runtime"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
],
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=840K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=840K(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=21.7M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=21.7M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nSTACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 \nStack                             8176K        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE                       13.3M        5 \nVM_ALLOCATE (reserved)             308K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\n__DATA                              80K        3 \n__DATA_CONST                        80K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                         240K        4 \n__TEXT                             624K        2 \nmapped file                        6.1G       33 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              6.2G       52 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     6.2G       52 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "61301e3a61217b3110231469",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_FIND_MY_CONFIGURATION_FILES" : "652886aa2c02f032beae8316"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000028
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60356660bbe37970735c5624",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000027
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "6dd670af-0633-45e4-ae5f-122ae4df02be",
      "experimentId" : "64406ba83deb637ac8a04419",
      "deploymentId" : 900000017
    }
  ]
},
  "reportNotes" : [
  "dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed"
]
}
```

If anyone can assist me with retaining my work whilst upgrading pgadmin or fixing this crashing issue it would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried running the installer again, downloading pgadmin separately etc.